# Regex Replacing Everything But Specific String Regex

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

How using regex would I take a string like "ratings-small star rating-4 field_stars_rating csm_review" and using gsub have it only return "rating-4", where 4 could be any digit? Anything I use replaces only partial bits

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` is the wrong choice here. It would make much more sense to do something like this:

```
"ratings-small star rating-4 field_stars_rating csm_review".match(/\brating-\d\b/).to_s
```

Because you're looking for a *specific* part of the string, it makes more sense to search directly for that.

To just get the number after the hyphen, use this:

```
"ratings-small star rating-4 field_stars_rating csm_review".match(/\brating-(\d)\b/)[0]
```

Comment: This worked really well! Question though, I'm rather new to regex, could you explain the meaning of \b? Thanks so much though!

Comment: Also, how could I make it so that it only returns the number, but still checks it is in the proper format?

Comment: @user3794461: `\b` matches a space. As for getting the number, see my edit.

Comment: @user3794461, get in the habit of reading the documentation before asking others. In the time it took you to ask and get a response, you could have found the answer yourself by reading [the Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) which explains it. Taking the initiative to learn on your own is an important skill for software developers.

Comment: To clarify: `\b` matches a "word boundary". It looks for: `^\w` (start of line, followed by a character), `\w$` (end of line, preceded by a character), `\w\W` (a word character followed by a non-word character), or `\W\w` (a non-word character followed by a word character). Word characters are defined to be letters, numbers, and only a small handful of symbols, and when used in `\brating-`, it ensures that the `r` in "rating" is the front of the word (and not within a word, like `crating`, `abracadabrating`, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to replace everything up to the position of the word or after the position of the digit you want matched, a better approach would be to [match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-match) that subpattern throughout your string.

```
string.match(/\b[a-z]+-\d+\b/i)
```

**Explanation:**

A word boundary does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not.

```
\b        # the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
 [a-z]+   #  any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or more times)
 -        #  '-'
 \d+      #  digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
\b        #  the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but *you* need to explain why yours is a better approach. Throwing out code without an explanation is like tossing the OP a fish. Instead teach the OP how to fish. Good answers have code and explain how it works.

Comment: @hwnd: I undid my downvote now that you stopped using (g)sub. Removing everything else in a string is not a good way to get something you're looking for, although that's what the OP originally asked.

Comment: @Linuxios I appreciate the feedback and explanation and I agree that gsub is not the best tool for this but I simply answered with what the OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to keep a bit of the string, instead of thinking how you can remove anything else to leave only the interesting bit, you should think how to extract the relevant part of the string. The [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method with a regexp argument would be my choice:

```
string = "ratings-small star rating-4 field_stars_rating csm_review"
string[/\brating-\d\b/]
# => "rating-4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with pure regex for this as it would make it pretty hard to read:

```
 string = "ratings-small star rating-4 field_stars_rating csm_review"
 string.split.select {|s| s =~ /^rating-\d$/}.join(' ')
```

If you expect only one element:

```
 string[/\brating-\d\b/]
```

Comment: I'm not sure your code is easier to read than a simple regex: `string[/(rating-\d+)/, 1]`.